# Socket bind port to same port in my localhost and box IP

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, netstat

I am trying to understand a setup and have highly confused my self.

Say my box IP is xx.xx.xx.xx and the 127.0.0.1 is Local Loopback of my Linux box. Now when I do a netstat for a port I see below output:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11191             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      9999/myexe        off (0.00/0/0)
tcp        0      0 xx.xx.xx.xx:11191           0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      26998/anotherexe        off (0.00/0/0)
```

What does the output basically means - since 127.0.0.1 and xx.xx.xx.xx refers to same box then does it means that two executable have binded and running at same port is same box - if so which binary would service the request if coming at port 11191 in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of those is almost certainly a different interface and hence a different internet address. That is, 127.0.0.1 is typically the loopback interface. While presumably xx.xx.xx.xx is a real (ethernet) network interface. It is entirely possible to have two separate programs bound to the same port number on separate addresses. It is more common that a single program simply binds to the port number and the kernel in effect translates that into multiple binds, one for each interface's address.

See `bind(2)` and `ip(7)` manual pages for details. Specifically, `INADDR_ANY` is the pseudo-address that can be used by a server that wishes to bind the port on all interfaces.

See also the answer here under the first paragraph of the Linux subheading:

[Socket options SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT, how do they differ? Do they mean the same across all major operating systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388706/socket-options-so-reuseaddr-and-so-reuseport-how-do-they-differ-do-they-mean-t)

Comment: "*It is entirely possible to have two separate programs bound to the same port number on separate addresses*" - and we can clearly see in the netstat output that is actually the case here.

Answer (score 1):

On some platforms, netstat can show you the processes that own the sockets. For example, on Windows, the `-b` switch displays executable names, and the `-o` switch displays process IDs. On Linux, the `-p` switch displays process information.

> does it means that two executable have binded and running at same port is same box

Yes. Your netstat output includes process names, so we can clearly see that `myexe` is listening on `127.0.0.1:11191` and `anotherexe` is listening on `xx.xx.xx.xx:11191`.

> if so which binary would service the request if coming at port 11191 in my case?

It depends on which local IP the connection arrives on.  `127.0.0.1` is a loopback adapter, so only clients running on the same machine can connect to it.  If a client connects to port 11191 on `127.0.0.1` specifically, `myexe` will handle the connection.  If a client connects to port 11191 on `xx.xx.xx.xx`, `anotherexe` will handle the connection.